# Error on Cout but i am not using Count in my LINQ exrpression,

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am trying to return a set of data in JSON formate from a LINQ select ran against my EF Code First DB and am getting the error

> Count must be a DbConstantExpression or a DbParameterReferenceExpression. Parameter name: count

but I am not sure why I am getting it as I am not using a `COUNT` parameter in my LINQ query so why am I getting this error?

```
    public ActionResult GetData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
    {
        try
        {
            //Get total rows
            int RowCount = db.Sections.Count();

            string OrderBy = (sidx + " " + sord);

            var SectionData = new
            {
                total = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)RowCount / (float)rows),
                page = page,
                records = RowCount,
                rows = (from s in db.Sections
                        select new
                        {
                            id = s.ID,
                            cell = new string[] {
                                SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)s.ID).Trim(),
                                s.RouteName,
                                s.Title
                            }
                            .OrderBy(x => sidx)
                            .Skip(page * rows)
                            .Take(rows)
                        }).ToArray()
            };
            return Json(SectionData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
            return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You are using RowCount for the total....I don't think thats the problem but it does do a count.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with EF, but I did come across an [old msdn post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/97338953-b9a8-4cc9-b14e-2132ba908528/a-possible-skiptake-operator-bug) where someone reported the same bug. They were performing a calculation inside `.Skip()` and to fix it they performed the calculation separately, and just used the result in their LINQ statement.

Try calculating `page * rows` first, then using that result in your LINQ statement:

```
var skipAmount = page * rows;

var SectionData = new
{
    ...
    ...
    rows = (from s in db.Sections
            select new
            {
                ...
                ...
                .OrderBy(x => sidx)
                .Skip(skipAmount)
                .Take(rows)
```

Comment: Yep that was the problem. Made a new variable called "SkipCount" to do the math and placed that in the `Skip()` and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Now with EF6 you can have lambda expressions in your Skip and Take parameters, and in fact its better to do so as the SQL Query is cached and re-used on subsequent pages: [see this article](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2016/12/06/skip-take-entity-framework-lambda.aspx)

But you still need to have evaluated the parameter to pass as @Grant does. So the difference being

```
.Skip(() => skipAmount
.Take(() => rows)
```